# IntelliJ IDEA 12 Scala Play SBT_VERSION error when create new project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Play plugin is enabled.
Downloaded Play from http://www.playframework.com/download 2.2.1 zip 104.8MB.

When I try to create Play Scala project in intelliJ IDEA 12 gives me error as below.

How to configure SBT?

**Note:** *But if I download Play from IntelliJ IDEA 12 than everything is fine but intelliJ downloading old version like play-2.1.0 but latest is 2.2.1*

[image: Play1]

[image: Play2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before as well. I tend to use the play command to generate my new projects and then idea with-sources=yes after the project is set up.

Comment: What you said above is the way to go. After some reading everything is clear now. Explained here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because Play 2.2.x is using SBT 0.13. IDEA 12 does not support SBT 0.13. The development is on-going for IDEA 13 to support SBT 0.13, but currently IDEA 13 is still in Beta.

If you look at the Github project for IntelliJ-SBT, you can see that a commit just comes in on Nov 6 (today) with update to support IDEA 13. The first beta for IDEA 13 is available today as well (Nov 6, 2013).

That is the reason why when you download Play from IDEA 12, it only gets you Play 2.1.x.

My recommendation is to switch to Scala IDE until you get IDEA 13, or use Play 2.1 for now. I found that most libraries are just catching up with 2.2 anyways.

I don't have commercial version of IDEA to verify this, so please let me know if this match what you see.